# Vaadin Dashboard demo using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, demo

I'm trying to put together a simple application using Vaadin + Spring Boot with just two views: login and dashboard. I'm using pieces of code from the [Vaadin Dashboard demo](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo). There is this method in the `DashboardUI` class:

```
private void updateContent() {
    User user = (User) VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute(
            User.class.getName());
    if (user != null && "admin".equals(user.getRole())) {
        // Authenticated user
        setContent(new MainView());
        removeStyleName("loginview");
        getNavigator().navigateTo(getNavigator().getState());
    } else {
        setContent(new LoginView());
        addStyleName("loginview");
    }
}
```

As you see the views are instantiated via the `new` keyword. Since I'm using Spring I would like the container take care of that. **But I cannot figure out how to have the views injected by Spring.**

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your view with `@VaadinUIScope` and `@VaadinComponent`. And then you can use `@Autowired` to inject your view.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably setup two UI classes i.e LoginUI.class and MainUI.class. Have Spring Security redirect unauthorized to **/login** and authorized to **/**

**LoginUI.class**

```
@Theme("valo")
@SpringUI(path = "login")
@PreserveOnRefresh 
public class LoginUI extends UI {

   private SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

   @Autowired
   public LoginUI(SpringViewProvider viewProvider) {
      this.viewProvider = viewProvider;
   }

   @Override
   protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
      Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
      navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);
      navigator.navigateTo(LoginView.VIEW_NAME);
   }

}
```

**MainAppUI.class**

```
@Theme("valo")
@SpringUI
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class MainAppUI extends UI {

    private SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

    @Autowired
    public AppUI(SpringViewProvider viewProvider) {
       this.viewProvider = viewProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

        getPage().setTitle("Main App");

        setSizeFull();

        Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, viewDisplay);
        navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);

        setContent();//viewport

       navigator.navigateTo(DashboardView.VIEW_NAME);
    }
}
```

Then just use @SpringView(name = "moduleOne", ui = MainAppUI.class) on your module views for your app as suggested by Morfic to have the main navigator and module views registered only when a user has logged in to save on resources.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

*Note*: Taking a look at that example it seems that they're not actually using views & navigator, they're somewhat faking them. If you want to proceed on the same path you can simply autowire the fake views in the UI instead of using the navigator as below.

The [Vaadin-spring boot wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=III+-+Views+and+Navigation+with+Vaadin+Spring) offers an introduction to this by the use of:

1) `@SpringUI` with autowired `SpringViewProvider`

```
@Theme("valo")
@SpringUI
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI {

    // we can use either constructor autowiring or field autowiring
    @Autowired
    private SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        // other init stuff
        Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, viewContainer);
        navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);
    }
}
```

2) `@SpringView`

```
@SpringView(name = DefaultView.VIEW_NAME)
public class DefaultView extends VerticalLayout implements View {
    public static final String VIEW_NAME = "";

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        addComponent(new Label("This is the default view"));
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        // the view is constructed in the init() method()
    }
}
```

For the decision whether the user should be redirected to the login view, or the other ones, I usually use a `ViewChangeListener`, something along the lines of:

```
navigator.addViewChangeListener(new ViewChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean beforeViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        if (VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("user") == null) {
            navigator.getDisplay().showView(loginView);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        // meh
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not that I want to proceed the way they are doing it. What would be a better option? How would I do it with a navigator? Is it possible to have one navigator and navigate between those two views, and then, when the user is logged in, use it to navigate inside the dashboard?

Comment: Any approach is valid and in the end it really depends what you need/want to do. Take a look at the [reasoning behind the navigator](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.navigator.html) that the Vaadin book offers, think about what you're after, and then decide on which path to follow.